# Adding object to list in a class

Tags: python, class

```
class Message_Board:

   def __init__(self,name):
       self.messages = []

   def add_message(self, message=None, text='', author='Unknown'):
      if(message == None):
         self.messages = Message(text, author) ###
      else:
         self.messages.append(message) ###
```

I'm having trouble with the `add_message` method, specifically with the two lines that I have marked `###`. I want to be able to add a message object to self.messages with the used being able to put the message in 2 different ways. If the message object is passed in, then the text and author should be ignored but if an object is not passed in, then it should create a new object using the text and author. I don't want to change the original `def add_message()` line.

Comment: What *"trouble"*, precisely? Give a [mcve]. One obvious issue is that only one of the branches adds to, rather than replacing, the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` in both cases:

```
class Message_Board:

   def __init__(self,name):
       self.messages = []

   def add_message(self, message=None, text='', author='Unknown'):
      if message is None:
         self.messages.append(Message(text, author))
      else:
         self.messages.append(message)
```